# GHC 7.8 binding substitution fails to type check

Tags: haskell, ghc

Given the support code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules, DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}
import Data.Typeable
default(A)
data A = A deriving (Eq,Show,Typeable)

class Show a => Testable2 a where
instance (Show a, Eq a) => Testable2 a where
instance (Show a, Testable2 b) => Testable2 (a -> b) where
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a -> b) where show _ = "<func>"

test :: (Show p, Typeable p, Testable2 p) => p -> IO ()
test = print . typeOf
```

In GHC 7.6, I can write:

```
main = test (\f -> (f $))
```

And that type checks, and prints:

```
(A -> A) -> A -> A
```

However, in GHC 7.8 I get:

```
Main.hs:
    No instance for (Eq (a0 -> b0)) arising from a use of `test'
```

But, if I refactor to:

```
main = let ff = \f -> (f $) in test ff
```

Then it works properly in both GHC 7.8 and GHC 7.6. Why?

The logic behind the support code is an instance for `Show (a -> b)` with `Show` context to force type defaulting, then a way of handling default atoms (with `Eq`), and a way of moving something back over an `->` for `Testable2`. The code is designed to allow variable-arity QuickCheck properties, and is taken from [hlint](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint/blob/master/data/HLint_QuickCheck.hs).

Comment: What does `main = test ($)` give?

Comment: To answer my own question, in 7.8 it gives the same error as `test (\f -> (f $))`: "No instance for `(Eq (a0 -> b0))` arising from use of `test`"

Comment: Weird, if I do `main = test ((\f -> (f $)) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b)` then it compiles and produces `(A -> A) -> A -> A`, but if I leave off the type signature I get an error.  This works for `main = test (($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b)` as well.

Comment: Also, `test id` compiles while `test (\f -> f)` does not.

Comment: It seems that `test (\ x -> x)` does not even compile with GHC 7.6.3. On the other hand, `($$) = ($); main = test (\ f -> (f $$))` compiles with both. I suspect defaulting not taking place for ungeneralized/monomorphic type variables in combination with special built-in treatment of `($)`.

Comment: @kosmikus that's the best answer so far, want to turn it into a real answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `test (\ x -> x)` does not even compile with GHC 7.6.3. On the other hand:

```
($$) = ($)
main = test (\ f -> (f $$))
```

compiles with both. I suspect defaulting not taking place for ungeneralized/monomorphic type variables in combination with special built-in treatment of `($)`.

Copied from users kosmikus' comment to the question.